# How to iterate through all sheets using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to iterate through all the tabs in a google spreadsheet and get their names. I tried using this function:

```
function init(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var r = sheets[i]
    Logger.log("sheet name:", r)
}
}
```

But the out-put that I get from this is:

```
sheet name: Sheet
sheet name: Sheet
sheet name: Sheet
sheet name: Sheet
sheet name: Sheet
```

Any suggestions about what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is logging the sheet object `{}`, which when stringified returns a literal `Sheet` string. You need to get it's name by calling the `Sheet` class' method `getName()`:

```
Logger.log("sheet name:", r.getName())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can literally achieve your goal with **one line** of code:

```
function init(){
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(r=>Logger.log("sheet name:", r.getName()));
}
```

As [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65369376/11225291) mentioned you need to get the **name** of the sheet. You are now logging **instances** of the [sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).